# Adding functions to Java class libraries

Tags: java, function, casting, class

I'm using a Java class library that is in many ways incomplete: there are many classes that I feel ought to have additional member functions built in. However, I am unsure of the best practice of adding these member functions.

Lets call the insufficient base class `A`.

```
class A
{
    public A(/*long arbitrary arguments*/)
    {
        //...
    }

    public A(/*long even more arbitrary arguments*/)
    {
        //...
    }

    public int func()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to add a function to `A`. However, I can't do that. My choice is between:

```
class B extends A
{
    //Implement ALL of A's constructors here

    public int reallyUsefulFunction()
    {
        return func()+1;
    }
}
```

and

```
class AddedFuncs
{
    public static int reallyUsefulFunction(A a)
    {
        return a.func()+1;
    }
}
```

The way I see it, they both have advantages and disadvantages. The first choice gives a cleaner syntax than the second, and is more logical, but has problems: Let's say I have a third class, `C`, within the class library.

```
class C
{
    public A func()
    {
        return new A(/*...*/);
    }
}
```

As I see it, there is no easy way of doing this:

```
C c;
int useful = c.func().reallyUsefulFunction();
```

as the type returned by `C.func()` is an `A`, not a `B`, and you can't down-cast.

So what is the best way of adding a member function to a read-only library class?

Comment: @Eric: usually in Java functions are referred to as "methods" even when they're, well, functions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural and frequent dilemma. Read about the [**composition vs inheritance**](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) alternative. Your second alternative is basically a composition, if we think that the object A is passed in the constructor instead of passing it in each method - that is, we would be using composition to implement a  **wrapper** or [**decorator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

The issue for class C returning a new instance of class A has no trivial solution, as you guessed, as long as class C decides to take responsability of creating the new instance. This is why one should pause and think before typing a "new" statement inside a class, if there is the possibility that this class will be subclassed. In yout example, it would be nice if you could tell class C what concrete class to return ... but how would it know to create it? Well we could pass him an object who knows how to instantiate an object of class A (or a subclass)... I guess you are enough motivated to read about [**Factories**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) now, and design patterns in general.

There is no unique best answer, but if want a quick one: I'd make a wrapper, B class does not extend A but has a constructor with A as parameter, it delegates its methods (except the own) to the inside object.
When you need to call the method in class C (I'm assuming you cant touch class C), you could write: `B b = new B(c.func())`

Comment: The only way I can touch class C is to derive another modified class from it, and doing so soon makes code unreadable.

Is there an easy way way to make `B` extend `A`, and give it a constructor that takes an `A` as an argument?

Comment: No, you are mixing things here (precisely composition and inheritance). Inheritance and decorator (implemented by composition) and two alternative ways you can "touch" a class (i.e. adding behaviour-state to it). If you read about it, you'll find that inheritance is frequently overrated by those new to OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Composition instead of Inheritance?

```
class ABetterA {
    private A a;

    public ABetterA() {

    }

    // write wrapper methods calling class' A methods and maybe doing something more
}
```

This way, you could also mimic multiple inheritance...

Answer (score 1):

You have a third option. You could use Scala (a Java compatible language) and its [traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126), which are [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) by another name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option. I'm using a Java subset for a robotics platform (LeJOS NXJ).

Answer (score 0):

Another option similar to Brian's sugestion is to use **Aspect Oriented Programming** (AOP) tool, such as **ApectJ**, which let you "inject" additional functionality into existing classes, even binary ones. You either preprocess the library jar to get a new one with enhanced classes ("static weaving") or you can do all of this at runtime when the library classes are loaded (so called "load-time weaving"). You can check this [AspectJ example](http://jroller.com/holy/entry/enforcing_a_common_log_format).

Even though AOP is normally used to modify existing methods (before, after or around "advices" = code pieces) you can also introduce new members and methods - check [AspectJ's Inter-type declarations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#inter-type-declarations).

Of course there is the question whether AspectJ is supported at your limited platform.