# Add Function to BigDecimal variables

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I working with some calculations - where I all the time use BigDecimal. I have created special util for that to make it easier to make comparisons:

```
public class BigDecimalUtil {

    public static boolean isZero(BigDecimal value) {
        return value == null?false:value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0;
    }   

    public static boolean isPositive(BigDecimal value) {
        return value == null?false:value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0;
    }

    public static boolean isNegative(BigDecimal value) {
        return value == null?false:value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0;
    }

    public static boolean isEqual(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.compareTo(value2) == 0;
    }

    public static boolean isLessThan(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.compareTo(value2) < 0;
    }

    public static boolean isMoreThan(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.compareTo(value2) > 0;
    }
}
```

But actually it is also not very comfortable to use some times.
Is there any way to add this functionality directly to Bigdecimal class?

Lets say something like this:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("0");
if(number.isPositive){
    //do something 
}
```

in this case isPositive is my function from util.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding functions to Java class libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761172/adding-functions-to-java-class-libraries)

Comment: Is it really that much trouble to compare to `BigDecimal.ZERO`? Just lose the `util` class it's just silly.

Comment: I'm working with financial resource where I need to have a lot of functions like - isZero, isEqual, isLessThan, isMoreThan, isNegative, isNegativeOrZero and using compare method believe me is not the best option. It also makes code harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible unless you're willing to extend the `BigDecimal` class, in which case you can try this:

```
public class BigDecimal2 extends BigDecimal {
    public boolean isPositive() {
        return compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Does this add the function `isPositive()` to the BigDecimal class? Or does this require you to wrap `new BigDecimal2(myValue).isPositive()` around every BigDecimal value before you can call `isPositive()`? If the latter, I don't see how this is any more "comfortable to use" [OP's words] than static methods in a BigDecimalUtil.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It would require wrapping, though that could be implemented within the class itself. I agree that it's not an ideal solution, but it's the only one Java offers to my knowledge.